# How to train a classifier that contain multi dimensional featured input values

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset, feed-forward

I am trying to model a classifier that contain Multi Dimensional Feature as input. Can any one knew of a dataset that contain multi dimensional Features?
Lets say for example: In mnist data we have pixel location as feature & feature value is a Single Dimensional grey scale value that varies from (0 - 255), But if we consider a colour image then in that case a single grey scale value is not sufficient, in this case also we will take the pixel location as feature but feature value will be of 3 Dimension( R(0-255) as one dimension, G(0-255) as second dimension and B(0-255) as third dimension) So in this case how can one solve using FeedForward Neural network? 
SMALL SUGGESTIONS ALSO ACCEPTED.

Answer (score 0):

The same way.

If you plug the pixels into your network directly just reshape the tensor to have H*W*3 length.

If you use convolutions note the the last parameter is the number of input/output dimensions. Just make sure the first convolution uses 3 as input.

Comment: Can we model that using feed forward neural network instead of convolutional neural network ?